# Duplicate and forward udp traffic

Tags: linux, iptables

is there any way to duplicate incoming udp traffic on port 162 and forward to multi ports like 162 itself and 1600? I was checking iptables but it seems only able to redirect to a single port/host.

Thx
Luke

Answer (score 3):

There is an experimental TEE target to iptables' mangle table which is part of the [Xtables-addons](http://xtables-addons.sourceforge.net/) (ex patch-o-matic) which is able to copy a packet without changes to another gateway. There you could NAT to another port, if still needed.

Answer (score 1):

flow-fanout will do what you want:

http://www.splintered.net/sw/flow-tools/docs/flow-fanout.html

Comment: it likely won't - flow-fanout is to replicate NetFlow exports, not generic UDP data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can also configure net-snmp as a trap receiver to relay traps to other devices if you have multiple monitoring stations you are trying to send data to.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [samplicator](https://github.com/sleinen/samplicator) which also seems to do this.

Comment: +1 for samplicator - it appears to be exactly what we need for duplicating statsd traffic to ensure HA on our Graphite solution.